# Testcafe throws error running a test in chrome when visiting react application on localhost

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an issue, which seems something like a CORS issue.
We have a react application which I'm running locally.

When I visit `http://localhost:3000` it will redirect to a keycloak authorization page on our development server `http://dev.domain/auth`. After logging in you will be redirected back to your origin (in this case localhost)

When I run my test in Chrome: `npx testcafe chrome features`, the browser is started and you can see localhost is visited and the redirect is triggered, but then an error is thrown by testcafe.

```
Running tests in:
 - Chrome 69.0.3497 / Linux 0.0.0

 Demo testing the React Demo App
 /home/data/react-demo-app/node_modules/testcafe-hammerhead/lib/request-pipeline/connection-reset-guard.js:27
 throw err;
 ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:866:14)
```

I've tried to run with websecurity disabled
`npx testcafe 'chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir' features` but this did not fix it.

And when I tried running it in Firefox, it ran without any issues.

```
Running tests in:
 - Firefox 61.0.0 / Ubuntu 0.0.0

 Demo testing the React Demo App
 ✓ Login and ...


 1 passed (21s)
```

I suspect some sort of cross domain reference error, because when I run the test against the development server in Chrome, all works fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The TestCafe team has fixed a similar issue before. Would you please clarify which TestCafe version you are using?

Comment: @Marion I'm using TestCafe **0.22.0**

Answer (score 2):

The TestCafe team has fixed this issue for Windows. Now, they are going to fix it for Linux as well. Please track the following thread to be notified of the progress:

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/1647

**UPDATE**: we fixed it for Linux too.